Main actor-isolated property using @preconcurrency Swift 6 migration issue
I am migrating our app to Swift 6, and I am encountering the following error while trying to migrate part of the code base.
Xcode 16 with swift 6 asked me to add the @preconcurrency attribute before the protocol name (see image in point 1). However, when I switch to Xcode 15.4 with swift 5, it asks me to place the @preconcurrency attribute at the beginning of the extension (see image in point 2). If I do this, it then asks me to remove it (see image in point 3).
Is there any way to make this Swift 6 migration change work in both Swift 5.1 and 6.0?
Does anyone know how to fix this?
1 - This is the error I got when I used it with Xcode 16 and Swift 6:

2 - This is the error I got after applying the Xcode suggestion from point 1, using Xcode 15.4 and Swift 5.1:

3 - This is the error I got after applying the Xcode suggestion from point 2, using Xcode 15.4 and Swift 5.1.

This is the simplified version of the code base:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

extension ContentView: NamedView {
    var analyticsName: String { "test" }
}

protocol NamedView {
    var analyticsName: String { get }
}


Just add MainActor to the protocol

@loremipsum, thanks, it looks like it works fine. I need to fix a different part of the codebase now, but that part works just fine. I'm wondering why the compiler recommends using preconcurrency when this doesn't compile in previous Xcode versions.

No idea that is an Apple thing. I only add preconcurrency to Apple frameworks with little risk of causing races and as a last resort. I think I have only done it twice so far.
